# Google Slides API (Slides.Presentations) is undefined via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I'm facing an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'batchUpdate' of undefined"

when I use the following code in my GAS:

```
var batchUpdateResponse = Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(
  {
    requests: requests
  },
  presentationId
);
```

Google Slides API are enabled on both Cloud Console and Advanced Service in Resource of GAS.

Looks like Slides is called properly, since I run `console.info(Slides)` then get `[Function: Slides]`.

However, `Slides.Presentations` is not called properly since `console.info(Slides.Presentations)` shows `undefined`.

Appreciated if someone can help.

Comment: looks like you have redefined `Slides` in your code somewhere

Comment: Can you provide your whole releveant code snippet including `requests`?

Comment: Thanks Kos and ziganotschka!
Even I have simple code like below, it got undefined error.

function test () {
  console.info(Slides);
  console.info(Slides.Presentations);
}

First console.info shows "[Function: Slides]", however second console.info shows "undefined".

Comment: Are you using Rhino or v8? Is your Apps Script project bound to a standard GCP project? Is it an alone-standing script or bound to a Slides document? Doy you have more than 1 script file in your Apps Script project? Create a brand new Apps Script file and run your simple code - it should not result in any error if Advanced Slides Service is enabled.